# Select all rows as objects in Oracle

Tags: oracle, object

On PostgreSQL, I can get all rows of table `tablename` as objects:

```
SELECT t FROM tablename t;
```

When I'm trying this on Oracle, it's not working, Is there anyway of doing it? I'm new to Oracle.

Comment: Based on the deleted answer and your comment under it, I edited your question to clarify. I hope I got it right. Otherwise, feel free to [edit] it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL fiddle doesn't format the object as nicely as other IDEs but:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0e39/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  a VARCHAR( 200 ),
  b INTEGER
)
/
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ( 'a', 1 )
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab1_type IS OBJECT(
  a VARCHAR2( 200 ),
  b INTEGER
)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT tab1_type( a, b ) FROM tab1 t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0e39/1/0)**:

```
|             TAB1_TYPE(A,B) |
|----------------------------|
| oracle.sql.STRUCT@1073bf6b |
```